# STL map container with values of type boost::circular_buffer

Tags: c++, boost, stl, buffer, pcap

## Introduction

I am writing an app that needs the ability to track the throughput of discreet profiles of network traffic (using libpcap, of course).  The basic idea is to accumulate byte and packet counters during each regular sample interval and use that to calculate average throughput on about a 1-second interval.

## Details

Each data point is distinguished by both the remote address and remote port.  They will store a (very short) sample history in a circular buffer made up of the following structure:

```
typedef struct {
  struct timeval ts_start;  // Time at the start of this sample
  size_t packets;           // packet count during this sample
  size_t bytes;             // byte count during this sample
} Sample;
```

My initial thought is to do something with STL and Boost similar to the following:

```
typedef std::pair<unsigned long /* addr */, unsigned short /* port */> PeerSpec;
typedef boost::circular_buffer<Sample> DataPoint;
std::map<PeerSpec, DataPoint> tracked_peers;
```

Each circular buffer will have a small number of elements, that number defined as `1 + summary_interval / sample_period`.  I was thinking that with a summary interval of 1 second, then a sample period of 250-1000 milliseconds would be appropriate (meaning 2-5 samples of history per data point).

Each data point would be instantiated and added to the `tracked_peers` map dynamically when such traffic is observed in capture.  Naturally, the counters would be updated by my pcap callback on a packet-by-packet basis.

## Question

Is it crazy/unwise/impossible to do this in this way?  I'm worried that it may not be fast enough to keep up with the packet capture.  Are there any copy semantics I need to be aware of?  I think it should be appropriate as long as I'm not causing circular buffers to be copied in whole with every update.  I'm asking because I'm not sure if I fully grasp all of the implications.

Comment: Thanks--this would be one of those implications of which I'm not aware.  What sort of housekeeping does a std::map do that might be undesirable?  I thought map would be the best container because its [] operator returns a reference and there will only be one such container in the app (maybe I'm wrong or overlooking something else?).

Comment: std::map has some copy overhead when adding element. The value will be copied at least three times before it will end up in map node structure. But the value retrieved from the map is a reference so there is no additional coping when accessing the map (assuming the element already exists).

Comment: Such overhead at the time of creating the data point is how I imagined and should be ok.  If I can update the circular buffers in-place without causing any extraneous copying, that would be optimal.  I guess I should put together a proof of concept and see if it works and maybe take some measurements.  Thanks for your insight, guys!

Comment: @MaciekB: Why would insertion take at least three copies? In my head it can be done in one *move* or copy, or if you emplace directly *none*.

Comment: @GManNickG: map stores content as std::pair<key, value> so in order to insert an element you have to create a pair. So the first copy constructor is run when the pair is created. std::map also makes assumption that key is constant so the actual value stored is std::pair<const key, value>. In this example we have std::map<PeerSpec, DataPoint> so the second copy will be made when  std::pair<const PeerSpec, DataPoint> is created. And finally the third copy is made when the value is stored in the tree node. Write a class that logs each copy constructor call and try inserting objects into map

Comment: @MaciekB: You're right, I forgot about all the messy conversions. None of those have to be copies though, they're all moves. Emplace does move once.

Comment: @GManNickG: that's right - you can define move constructor. And by defining key constant you can reduce moves/copies to only 2

Comment: This is a very informative discussion.  I guess what I really need to work out is how these containers behave internally--specifically whether or not circular_buffer implements move constructors. (not a question to you guys, I think I can figure that part out on my own)

Comment: It seems that `boost::circular_buffer` [does not support move semantics](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7888).